# Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо запарсить годовую отчетность с ЦБРФ, а именно Бухгалтерский баланс и отчет о финансовых результатах, используя python

Tags: python, парсер, поиск-библиотек

Основная ссылка: https://www.cbr.ru/banking_sector/credit/FullCoList/
Какие python библиотеки посоветуете использовать?
Это мой первый опыт в парсинге сайтов, буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Какие библиотеки вы уже нашли, что попробовали и на чем остановились?

Comment: pandas, selenium, beautiful soup

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам надо запарсить таблицу, которая находится по Вашей ссылке, используйте `pandas`:

`pip install pandas`

`pip install lxml`

Вот код парсинга таблицы:

```
import pandas
pars = pandas.read_html("https://www.cbr.ru/banking_sector/credit/FullCoList/")
print(pars)
```

Вывод:

```
[     № п/п  ...                                    Местонахождение
0        1  ...  362040, Республика Северная Осетия-Алания, г.В...
1        2  ...          127051, г. Москва, Цветной бульвар, д. 18
2        3  ...       119180, г. Москва, ул. Большая Якиманка, д.1
3        4  ...             420111, г.Казань, ул.Мусы Джалиля, д.3
4        5  ...      109028, г.Москва, Серебряническая наб., д. 29
..     ...  ...                                                ...
674    675  ...   119034, г. Москва, Пречистенская набережная, д.9
675    676  ...  127083, г. Москва, ул. Верхняя Масловка, д. 20...
676    677  ...    117449, г. Москва, ул. Новочерёмушкинская, д.10
677    678  ...  115035, г. Москва, ул. Садовническая, д. 82 ст...
678    679  ...             150000, г.Ярославль, ул.Собинова, д.30
```

**Документация по действиям с данной структурой:** [тык](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#min)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уточню свой вопрос, мне нужно, чтобы программа переходила по ссылкам банков и копировала "Отчет о финансовых результатах" и "Данные оборотной ведомости по счетам бухгалтерского учета"